# How to create and fill cells with different types in the tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a model class with 3 properties and tableview with three cells and each one has its own custom class.

How to install and fill three different cells from the same model correctly?

```
@interface Movie : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *posterImage;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *overview;
@end


@interface MoviePosterCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *poster;
@end

@interface MovieTitleCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *title;
@end

@interface MovieOverviewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *overview;
@end
```

I tried to do something like this, but it seems to me wrong because if I want to reorder or add a new cell I will have to install everything manually.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        MovieOverviewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([MovieOverviewCell class]) forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.poster = self.movie.posterImage;
        return cell;
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        MovieTitleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([MovieTitleCell class]) forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.title = self.movie.title;
        return cell;
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        MovieOverviewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([MovieOverviewCell class]) forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.overview = movie.overview;
        return cell;
    }

    return [UITableViewCell new];
}
```

Comment: You need to add a logic to keep the order of the cells. And you wrote *..or add a new cell*. What do you want to display in the new cell? Your data source is **one** `Movie` object. A better solution might be to create **one** custom cell which can display all three properties.

Comment: What UI you want to achieve? Could you add some mockup?

Comment: In the future I want to get something like that https://ibb.co/5M5Stc6